# how to display a row that is null instead of 0

Tags: sql, oracle, null

I am getting a correct result, but now instead of showing me result that is 0 I want them to show me null result . How could I get results null instead of 0 ?

```
SELECT w.FIRST_NAME,w.LAST_NAME,COUNT(s.SECTION_ID) AS COUNTED_SECTIONS
FROM INSTRUCTOR w LEFT OUTER JOIN SECTION s 
ON w.INSTRUCTOR_ID = s.INSTRUCTOR_ID
GROUP BY w.FIRST_NAME,w.LAST_NAME
ORDER BY w.LAST_NAME;
```

currently showing

```
FIRST_NAME                LAST_NAME                 COUNTED_SECTIONS
------------------------- ------------------------- ----------------
Rick                      Chow                                     0 
Marilyn                   Frantzen                                10 
Fernand                   Hanks                                    9 
Charles                   Lowry                                    0
etc
```

but I want

```
FIRST_NAME                LAST_NAME                 COUNTED_SECTIONS
------------------------- ------------------------- ----------------
Rick                      Chow                                      
Marilyn                   Frantzen                                10 
Fernand                   Hanks                                    9 
Charles                   Lowry                                    
etc
```

I've tried it with NVL and it doesn't work

```
NVL(COUNT(s.SECTION_ID),NULL) AS COUNTED_SECTIONS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `NULLIF()` is available in oracle:

```
SELECT w.FIRST_NAME,w.LAST_NAME,NULLIF(COUNT(s.SECTION_ID),0) AS COUNTED_SECTIONS
FROM INSTRUCTOR w LEFT OUTER JOIN SECTION s 
ON w.INSTRUCTOR_ID = s.INSTRUCTOR_ID
GROUP BY w.FIRST_NAME,w.LAST_NAME
ORDER BY w.LAST_NAME;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try nullif:

```
SELECT w.FIRST_NAME,w.LAST_NAME, NULLIF(COUNT(s.SECTION_ID), 0) AS COUNTED_SECTIONS
FROM INSTRUCTOR w LEFT OUTER JOIN SECTION s 
ON w.INSTRUCTOR_ID = s.INSTRUCTOR_ID
GROUP BY w.FIRST_NAME,w.LAST_NAME
ORDER BY w.LAST_NAME;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DECODE](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/decode.php) in order to decide what you want to display

```
DECODE(COUNT(s.SECTION_ID),0, NULL, COUNT(s.SECTION_ID)) AS COUNTED_SECTIONS
```

Comment: Did not know about DECODE FUNCTION, good to know and thanks for sharing.